# Using trans in templates

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm currently using Twig templates and translations in a symfony project and a little problem came up.

I've checked the documentation but I can't figure that out.

I have a translation file (in yml), its configuration's like this.

```
    productMissingMessage: El producto con referencia %productRef% ha sido descatalogado en nuestra tienda.
```

In the twig template, I have something like this:

```
   {% for product in productsDeleted %}
      <p>{{'basket.productMissingMessage'|trans }}</p>
   {% endfor %}
```

It may sound stupid, but I'm struggling in how to add a parameter in there to get the value out to the trans file.
I've seen in the documentation that you can add a string or a number, but never a variable, in this case, the variable will be {product}.

This is a documentation example:

```
    {{ message|trans({'%name%': 'Fabien'}, "app") }}
```

Any idea how to pass the value of the variable? I've tried with {{product}} but nope.

Comment: ...the value of which variable? Is there anything not workign when you exchange the static string `'Fabien'` with any variable?

Answer (score 1):

Could you try this:

```
{% for product in productsDeleted %}
    <p>{{'basket.productMissingMessage'|trans({'%productRef%': product}, "app") }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```